# Unable to identify issue with Ajax call to Yii API getting no response headers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, yii

**Overview**

I'm currently working on a jQuery/HTML5 project that displays web performance data with a series of charts using an internal API to retrieve the data. The API is powered by Yii, but I am not working on it, so i cannot change or experiment with it myself.

Basically I am hoping someone can help identify if the API is the root cause of the problem or if it's a problem with the Ajax in my jQuery being incorrect.

A small explanation of the process my application goes through...

1. Application loads, uses user details to authenticate with API. Receives API Key from API.
2. After the key has been retrieved, several calls are made to retrieve data from the APi to display as the web performance data.
3. At set intervals, a generic is called to the database to check that the API Key has expired or not.
4. If the key has expired, it makes another request to the API for a new API Key as stated in step 1. If there are any problems with gaining an API key, this is when the user gets kicked off.
5. Restart cycle excluding getting the data.

**Problem**

All Ajax calls are made to the are crossdomain as both the project and the API are on separate sub domains. These are done using JSONP and a jQuery callback.

The problem I am having is that when I need to authenticate if the key is valid or not, if it is no longer valid, the API returns a 401 error which my Ajax does not register. If i view the API URL in Firefox, I can see the returned Json data, wrapped in a callback, but when I check firebug it says there is a request, but no response.

Basically when the API returns data that is not 200 OK, it doesn't send a response header at all.

However I have manually called the API using cUrl in terminal, and have received a response header, as well as in Google Chrome.

If someone could tell me if this is a well known issue with Firefox/jQuery or if this is a problem with the Yii API I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you turn on Jquery's cross domain support?

Comment: Not consciously, is this something i would need to setup on the client or in the code?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this before your ajax call:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting in IE
```